# What is the minimal time to move from the left to the right in a double potential well?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, hilbert-space, potential, time-evolution

Consider a particle in a double potential well with Hamiltonian $\hat{H}$ and two basis states $|l\rangle, |r\rangle$ which correspond to the particle being maximally localized in the left resp. right well. Assume now that the time evolution operator of the system admits the form $\hat{U}(t)=\cos(\varphi(t))\mathbb{1}+i\sin(\varphi(t))\hat{\sigma}_1$ where $\varphi(t)$ is some angle, $\mathbb{1}$ denotes the identity and $\hat{\sigma}_1$ denotes the first Pauli operator, given as a matrix by $\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 \\
1 & 0 
\end{pmatrix}$ if we fix the basis $\{|l\rangle, |r\rangle\}$.

**Assignment:** Assume that at time $t=0$, the system is in the state $|l\rangle$. At what minimal time $\tilde{t}$ is it in the state $|r\rangle$?

---

According to my understanding, we need to solve $|r\rangle=\hat{U}(t)|l\rangle$ and by plugging $\hat{U}(t)$ from above in, this amounts to solving $ 0 =\cos(\varphi(t)) \text{ AND } -i=\sin(\varphi(t))$, the latter having no solution if the angle $\varphi(t)$ is real, which angles usually are.

**Question:** Is my approach/understanding of time evolution correct and if not, where lies my mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pauli matrix $\sigma_1$ given by

$$\sigma_1=\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1\\
1 & 0
\end{pmatrix} $$

Your approach is correct. At any time, The state given by
$$|\Psi(t)\rangle =\mathcal{U}(t)|\Psi(0)\rangle=\mathcal{U}(t)|l\rangle $$
Suppose at $t=t_0$, $|\Psi(t_0)\rangle=|r\rangle $ so
$$|r\rangle =\mathcal{U}(t_0)|l\rangle $$
And solve for $t_0$.

---

We required
$$\cos(\phi)=0\rightarrow \phi=\pi/2$$
$$|\Psi(t_0)\rangle = i|r\rangle =e^{i\pi/2}|r\rangle $$

Comment: Thanks sorry, my expression for $\sigma_x$  was only a typo but the rest of the computation used the correct expression. So solving for $t_0$ yields my problem. I have corrected my expression of $\sigma_x$ above.

Comment: Please find edit

Comment: Thanks a lot, now I think I understand: Being in the right well, we can also differ from $|r\rangle$ by a complex phase that leaves the ket normalised.